# siginterrupt does not kill process that create process

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am trying to kill a process with `siginterrupt`

When I run the following code:

```
import time
import signal
import multiprocessing
import os    

def x():
    time.sleep(10)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
p.start()
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
p.join(1)
print p.is_alive()
```

False is printed to the screen as expected 
but when I run the following code:

```
import time
import signal
import multiprocessing
import os    

def x():
    time.sleep(10)

def y():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
    p.start()
    p.join()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=y)
p.start()
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
p.join(1)
print p.is_alive()
```

True is printed

Why is the process still alive after `siginterrupt`?

Comment: `signal.SIGINT` does not kill the process. You should use `signal.SIGKILL`.

Comment: Also, which process do you want to kill? The parent or the child? Your title and your question are in two minds...

Comment: i want to kill the parent process
it may be possible to ignore signinterrupt but its still supposed to kill the process if it is not ignored so why the process is still alive?

Comment: `p.pid` refers to the pid of the child, not the parent.

Comment: well there are actually three processes here, the main process, the process that run y which is the son of the main process and the process that run x which is the son of the process that run y, i want to kill the process that run y